# install cron files directly

Tags: cron

I am maintaining my (per-user) cron files in git repo and would much prefer to install them in their locations. I understand that cron prefers you edit files manually ( yuck ) with `crontab -e`. This is not at all convenient for my deployment process where I'd *much* rather just place the file in it's location with appropriate ownership:

```sh
-rw------- 1 postgres crontab 242 Jan  8 08:38 /var/spool/cron/crontabs/postgres
```

Reading the file directly does not give me confidence that I should even try:

```sh
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - edit the master and reinstall.
# (/tmp/crontab.wksCRO/crontab installed on Fri Jan  8 08:38:11 2021)
# (Cron version -- $Id: crontab.c,v 2.13 1994/01/17 03:20:37 vixie Exp $)
# postgres
# m h  dom mon dow   command
```

I realize that it is *not* recommended, but, presuming I am careful to not introduce bugs, is there anything that actually stops me from simply overwriting cron files?

Comment: Most folks are "*careful to not introduce bugs*," but bugs and typos and mistakes and logical errors creep in. Make sure you test afterward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `crontab` command to install a new crontab file for a specified user in the correct location with the correct ownership and permissions

Ex. assuming your desired new crontab file for user `postgres` is named `crontab.postgres` then

```
sudo crontab -u postgres path/to/crontab.postgres
```